# Passing Object data to jQuery.post successor function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want this.item of an instance of the class to be filled by the data received through jQuery.post successor function. I am able to do this using some another user-defined function to set this.item with the data received.

Question : Is there any way to set this.item inside the successor function of jQuer.post() without using any other user-defined functions ?

Following is the code snippet

Inside Class Prototype function :-

```
   this.item = new Array();

   jQuery.post("index.php?p=getdataitem", fileobj,function(item_str_data)
              {
        ...
        this.item = ....;   
                ...
              }
   );
```

Thank You

Comment: Just don't use `this` keyword.

Comment: Either you need to specify `context` to the AJAX call (only possible with `$.ajax` not with `$.post` OR you can use a closure to be able to refernce your object from outside the success call handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
 this.item = new Array();
var instance = this;

   jQuery.post("index.php?p=getdataitem", fileobj,function(item_str_data)
              {
        ...
        instance.item = ....;   
                ...
              }
   );
```

OR

```
 this.item = new Array();

   jQuery.ajax(
         {url: "index.php?p=getdataitem", 
          context: this,
          success: function(item_str_data)
              {
                ...
                this.item = ....;   
                ...
              }
         }
   );
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your answers and explanations @Marcell Thanks A lot for the quick answer...working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  var that = this;
  var that.item = [];

  function() {

      jQuery.post("index.php?p=getdataitem", fileobj,function(item_str_data) {
        ...
        that.item = ....;   
        ...
      });

   }();
```

Because of the closure, the `this` reference we copy (`that`) should be available to the inner function of the post.